# HTTP Status 500 in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to create my first SpringMVC, and just in the beggin i am having some little errors to run my project. Follow the code and the logs.

Error Logs:

```
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringMVC' did not find a matching property.
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.8.5.4
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          Aug 2 2017 21:35:49 UTC
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server number:         8.5.20.0
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Windows 10
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            10.0
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          amd64
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Felipe\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Felipe\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Felipe\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\endorsed
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WUM\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Felipe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;$PATH:$CATALINA_HOME\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Felipe\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;;C:\Program Files\eclipse-Mars;;.]
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 827 ms
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service [Catalina]
fev 03, 2018 10:20:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.8.5.4
fev 03, 2018 10:20:23 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
fev 03, 2018 10:20:24 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
fev 03, 2018 10:20:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
fev 03, 2018 10:20:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springmvc'
fev 03, 2018 10:20:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFORMAÇÕES: FrameworkServlet 'springmvc': initialization started
fev 03, 2018 10:20:24 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFORMAÇÕES: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springmvc-servlet': startup date [Sat Feb 03 22:20:24 GMT-03:00 2018]; root of context hierarchy
fev 03, 2018 10:20:25 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFORMAÇÕES: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml]
fev 03, 2018 10:20:25 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
GRAVE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 28 more

fev 03, 2018 10:20:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 28 more

fev 03, 2018 10:20:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: Servlet [springmvc] in web application [/SpringMVC] threw load() exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

fev 03, 2018 10:20:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
fev 03, 2018 10:20:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
fev 03, 2018 10:20:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 2149 ms
fev 03, 2018 10:20:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springmvc'
fev 03, 2018 10:20:25 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFORMAÇÕES: FrameworkServlet 'springmvc': initialization started
fev 03, 2018 10:20:25 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFORMAÇÕES: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springmvc-servlet': startup date [Sat Feb 03 22:20:25 GMT-03:00 2018]; root of context hierarchy
fev 03, 2018 10:20:25 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFORMAÇÕES: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml]
fev 03, 2018 10:20:25 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
GRAVE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:712)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:110)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 54 more
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

     <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

springmvc-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">
    <bean name="index.html" class="br.com.informaticon.controller.controllerIndex"></bean>

</beans>
```

index.jsp:

```
<jsp:forward page="index.html"></jsp:forward>
```

controllerIndex.java:

```
package br.com.informaticon.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class controllerIndex implements Controller {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new ModelAndView("/home.jsp");
    }

}
```

**libs and structure**
[image: libs and structure]

**libs and structure_2**
[image: libs and structure_2]

Please help me i am really trying to learn. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Is your springmvc-servlet.xml file packaged in your .war where Spring is looking for it? The exception says it can't find it here: /WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml

Comment: yes in the prints posted you can see that he is in WebContent/WEB-INF

Comment: how are you building your war before you deploy? is this a maven based project?

Comment: try removing the init-param section. by default spring mvc will look for *-servlet.xml to match the name of your sevletname of your DispatcherServlet (I'm not sure if it's wrong, but I don't think it's needed)

Comment: Do you explicitly want do handle and learn spring mvc or do you want a web application built with spring?

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you so far. The project is a Dynamic Web Project, unfortunatelly i have to learn the spring mvc, because i am starting in a job where it will be required. I will try to take out the '-servlet', but i already take out the init-param, in fact before i worked without it and don't work.

Comment: I think that, maybe, my problem is the libraries, because i tryied another tutorial that worked, but i think that to my right learn, it is fundamental that i understand the reason that this isn't worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add view resolver to your springmvc-servlet.xml file. And also it needs to know where the controller files are. There is a great beginner project for spring MVC in Github, you can download end reverse engineer it. It is very helpful to me. [Here.](https://github.com/bh5k/spring_mvc_base)

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.informaticon.controller" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="2" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"
    p:order="0" />
```

Comment: Thank you Oguz. You helped me a lot.